# Cannot access file in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to read file from android device and upload it to server , my code is as following:

```
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(ForSaleConstants.REVIEW_IMAGE_UPLOADER, NetworkManager.CHARACTER_SET);
multipart.addFormField(ForSaleConstants.PHONE, phone);

String uriString = extraFileUri.toString();
Log.e("File_URI", uriString);
uriString = Uri.decode(uriString);
Log.e("File_URI2", uriString);

if (uriString.contains("file://")) {
   uriString = uriString.replace("file://", "");
   File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
   multipart.addFilePart(("image"), uploadFile);
} else if (uriString.contains("content://")) {
   uriString = FileManager.getInstance().getRealPathFromImageUri(context, Uri.parse(uriString));
   File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
   multipart.addFilePart(("image"), uploadFile);
} else {
   try {
      File uploadFile = new File(uriString);
      multipart.addFilePart(("image"), uploadFile);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I am getting the following crash:

```
    08-14 15:33:35.765 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:3954 from pid=22931, uid=10365 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:536)
08-14 15:33:35.778 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at com.technivance.q84sale.base.controller.manager.FileManager.getRealPathFromImageUri(FileManager.java:225)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at com.forsale.forsale.services.controller.manager.ServicesManager$29.doInBackground(ServicesManager.java:2797)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at com.forsale.forsale.services.controller.manager.ServicesManager$29.doInBackground(ServicesManager.java:2774)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
08-14 15:33:35.779 22931-23288/com.forsale.forsale W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Which part of the requiring permissions have you not done? Can you show your manifest?

Comment: Have you taken runtime permissions?

Comment: @cricket_007 please check my edit

Comment: Get rid of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />`, as that is a permission that you cannot hold. Please explain where this `Uri` is coming from, where the code in your question resides relative to that, and why you think that any `getRealPathFromImageUri()` method is going to work reliably.

Comment: please implement runtime permission, is you code working fine on Lollipop(21) device if so i pre-assume runtime permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give Runtime Permission use below link to get run time permission code and either ask on Splash or on the activity where you are using camera

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

You have must get/give run time permission in Android 6.0 (API level 23)

for more info : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html